# Are preattentive processes necessarily unconscious processes?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, consciousness, attention

**Are preattentive processes necessarily unconscious processes?**

If no, why not, and could you please provide an example of a preattentive process of which we are conscious?

If yes, why?

To the extent that I have a specific context in mind, I'm thinking of Neisser's postulation of a preattentive stage of visual processing.